# jQuery Deferred Official Example：then()

Tags: javascript, jquery

[jQuery: deferred.then()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)

I thought 'defer.resolve(5)' after 'filtered.done()' is correct, but why both have the same result.

```
var filterResolve = function() {
  var defer = $.Deferred(),
    filtered = defer.then(function( value ) {
      return value * 2;
    });

  defer.resolve( 5 );

  filtered.done(function( value ) {
    $( "p" ).html( "Value is ( 2*5 = ) 10: " + value );
  });
};
```

---

```
var filterResolve = function() {
  var defer = $.Deferred(),
    filtered = defer.then(function( value ) {
      return value * 2;
    });

  filtered.done(function( value ) {
    $( "p" ).html( "Value is ( 2*5 = ) 10: " + value );
  });

  defer.resolve( 5 );
};
```

Comment: It does not matter when you do the `resolve`, that's the whole point of promises - whenever the resolve happens, the registered handlers are executed. If the resolve already happened in the past, the handler gets executed right away (possibly queued up).

Comment: The functions are async so it doesn't matter when you resolve the first defer

Comment: @Chips_100. You are right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var defer = $.Deferred(),
    filtered = defer.then(function( value ) {
      return value * 2;
    });

defer.resolve( 5 );
 
$("button").on( "click", function(){
  filtered.done(function( value ) {
    $( "p" ).html( "Value is ( 2*5 = ) 10: " + value );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Filter Resolve</button>
<p></p>
```